# bootstrap datetimepicker, unable to convert date and time to UTC

Tags: jquery, momentjs, datetimepicker

This question may have been asking multiple times before, but I can't seem to find any relative info, so was wondering any of you can give me some ideas.

I'm using bootstrap datetimepicker to create a tool and I encounter the following problem which my input date and time is unable to convert to UTC time via moment.js

Code below:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#select').datetimepicker({
        format: 'ddd, MM-DD hh:mm A'
    });
     $('#select').on('dp.change', function (e) {
        $('#example').text(moment(e.date).format("ddd, MM-DD, h:mm A"));
    });

});

<div class='col-md-5'>
   <div class="form-group">
      <div class='input-group date' id='select'>
         <input type='text' class="form-control" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

<span id="example">__________</span>
```

When the value has been selected, the output is same as what you have chose, instead of converting to UTC automatically. Any help to point out where I did wrong would be appreciated!

Comment: The assumption here is that you want to convert *from local time* to UTC.  If you meant something else, please clarify.

Comment: Hi @Matt Johnson - thanks for the information here. Your response is very interesting and I would like to know more, hope you can provide some example. Assuming I want the select time always be New York time, regardless the time zones users belong to, and convert to UTC. How can I achieve the goal. I looked into the moment doc but wan't able to get a better idea of how. Any help would be greatly appreciate!

Comment: You would need to install moment-timezone, then set the `timeZone` option on the datepicker to `'America/New_York'`.  See [this part of the bootstrap-datetimepicker docs](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/blob/master/docs/Options.md#timezone).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, you are displaying your selected date using `.format()` and passing into it the same values you are requiring from the date picker.

If you want UTC format, don't use `moment().format()` but use `moment.utc().format()`

See moment.js docs [here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/)

Answer (score 1):

With `moment.js` you can convert your date to `utc` and then format it like

```
$('#example').text(moment(e.date).utc().format("ddd, MM-DD, h:mm A"));
```

Comment: Fixed this for you.  It wasn't converting before.